# Do I necessarily have to use 第 when talking about a page number?

Tags: grammar, usage

Can one say 打开书100页 or is it necessary to add 第 before 100?

I was thinking that it would be the difference between saying "open the book at/to page 100" (with 第) and "open the book 100 pages" (without 第, which sounds wrong to me).

Comment: 见１- １０ 页 see pp。１- １０，把书翻到(第)十页 turn to p. 10，iciba has： Open your book and turn it to page 78 打开书翻到78页

Answer (score 1):

First, '书' in '打开书100页'(open book 100 pages) can be omitted

Yes, if you omitted '第' in '打开第100页'(open page 100) and wrote "打开100页", the sentence could be interpreted as " open one hundred pages". For this very reason, 第 cannot be omitted.

Comment: If I don't omit 书 then 第 is obligatory either way?

Comment: 第 is obligatory, doesn't matter if you omit  书 or not